# Is OmniFaces compatible with JSF 2.2?

Tags: jsf, dependencies, omnifaces, jsf-2.2

As the questions states, is OmniFaces compatible with JSF 2.2? 
Will it have dependencies only on JSF or other Java EE dependencies as well? I.e. will it be able to run just with Tomcat + JSF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OmniFaces 1.6 showcase application has been tested on GlassFish 4 with Mojarra 2.2.2 and Tomcat 7.0.42 with Mojarra 2.2.3. There were no problems when using OmniFaces 1.6 with Mojarra 2.2.x. Only [Glassfish 4 has a problem](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20775) with using the `#{now}` and `#{startup}` beans from OmniFaces, but this is not OmniFaces' fault. For any known issues you can keep track of [known issues](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/wiki/Known-Issues-%28general%29) wiki.

OmniFaces 1.x has no other required dependencies than Servlet, EL and JSF, with the minimum versions 2.5, 2.1 and 2.0 respectively. Tomcat already provides Servlet and EL out the box. You only need to supply JSF yourself (which in turn has a dependency on JSTL 1.2 which is also absent on Tomcat).

Comment: BalusC: does jsf really depend on jstl?

Comment: For the `<c:xxx>` tags in Facelets, yes.

Comment: BalusC: Is Omnifaces compatible with Mojarra 2.3 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779638/conflict-between-omnifaces-cdi-param-and-jsf-2-3 )?